# Stop and Wait Link Utilization and Throughput

Tags: throughput, utilization

Consider the stop-and-wait data link protocol operating over a link whose parameters are as follows: `Tprop = d/v` where `d` is the distance between transmitter and receiver in meters and `v` is signal propagation speed in meters per second, and `Tf = L/R` where `L` is the frame length in bits, and `R` is the link transmission rate in bits per second. Ignoring the `Tack` and `Tproc` , it is required to answer the following questions:

a) Plot the link utilization as a function of the link transmission, `U(R)` for `R ϵ [0,∞)`.

b) Find the quantities `lim 'R→ ∞' U(R)` and `lim 'R→ 0+' U(R)`.

c) Plot the link throughput in bit per second, `Throbps(R)` for `R ϵ [0,∞)`.

d) Plot the link throughput in frames per second, `Throfps(R)` for `R ϵ [0,∞)`.

e) Find the quantities `lim 'R→ ∞' Throfps(R)` and `lim 'R→ 0+' Throfps(R)`.

The labels for all plots as well as all computed quantities should be in terms of the link parameters.

Comment: Part b) mean finding the limit (where R goes to infinity) for the function U(R); as well as part e). Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually I could observe how to answer the question
U(R) = (L/R) / ((L/R) + 2 Tprob)
Now:
by taking the limit:

lim 'R→ ∞' U(R) = lim 'R→ ∞' (L/R) / ((L/R) + 2 Tprob)

put R = ∞, we get:

(L/∞) / ((L/∞) + 2 Tprob) = 0 / (0+2Tprop) = 0

the same for lim 'R→ 0+'.

Also, the same for the throughput.

After we get the limits, we can plot the graph easily according to the values we get.

Regards,